# Azure Free Services Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, linux-networking

Am a new user to Azure, trying to learn Azure.
The first thing I tried is Azure free services and I have created 3 Linux Virtual machines using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in 3 different resource groups. Am not sure its strange or that's how it is all 3 Virtual machines getting same Private IP's. Please see the Pics attached.

2. Also, on above created resource groups, Azure is not allowing to create more virtual machines from free services.

My question is, is this is how Azure is for free services or I am doing it wrong or its a Bug which Azure needs to fix.

Please help.[Private_ip_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVhat.jpg)[Private_ip_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6efe.jpg)[Private_ip_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfQPT.jpg)[Resource_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Cx9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. It depends on your configuration. When you create a VM, you could use different Vnet which has different Address Space.

[image]

It seems your VMs use different Vnets but they use same address space. So, it is possible that your VMs use same private IP. But it does not affect your VM function. Because Virtual networks are isolated from one another. You can create separate virtual networks for development, testing, and production that use the same CIDR (10.0.0.0/0, for example) address blocks. Conversely, you can create multiple virtual networks that use different CIDR address blocks and connect the networks together. You can segment a virtual network into multiple subnets. Azure provides internal name resolution for resources deployed in a virtual network.

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview).

Comment: Thanks Shengbao, All this goes the way you explained if we create Virtual machines from compute section. but what i asked in my question is choosing VM creation from  " All Services --> Monitoring & Management --> Free Services --> Linux Virtual Machine Create. Moreover I dont have an option to select or choose internal network to create VM. Also irrespective of Loaction the Private IP always remains same. I understand what you said for Vnets. But think what if these 2 VM's need to communicate via Private IP's, how  you do that ??

Comment: Moreover, if you choose VM creation from free services you can't create more than 1 VM on same resource group.

Comment: @Tijo_V You should use different address space VNet. If they have same private IP, they could not communicate via private IP(public IP is possible). If your Vnets don't have IP address overlap, you could use Vnet to Vnet VPN to connect them.

Comment: @Tijo_V What VM size do you select, for a free subscription, it has some limit on VM cores.

Comment: not sure if its a problem or bug, but if we choose VM creation from free services I am seeing these 2 Issues.  Help me understand this correctly or guide me if am doing wrong. when I did chat with Azure support they told me why are you using free services to create VM. I hope in this forum no one will say me the same.. Thanks.

Comment: `free services to create VM` what do you mean?

Comment: Under free services Linux Virtual Machine
COMPUTE
750 hours
B1S

Comment: under Azure portal  follow this path All Services --> Monitoring & Management --> Free Services --> Linux Virtual Machine Create

Comment: Did you understood where am pointing to ??

Comment: @Tijo_V Sorry for my mistake, I understanding what you say. I think it is a design behavior. It is just a free service. If you want to use different private IP, you should use pay VM and select customize VM.

Comment: @Tijo_V Free service VM, you could not configure it. So they have same private IP.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you @Shengbao Shui - MSFT,  similarly it might be another design behavior not allowing more than 1 VM's under same ARM if we choose to create VM from free services.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Azure only provide free VM.

Comment: See this faq  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/

Comment: I hope I will get another yes from you for this, the faq statements regarding network are correct until we choose to create VM from free services. Thank you @Shengbao Shui - MSFT for all input provided.

Comment: @Tijo_V If my answer helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer. If you have other question, please let me know.